# User Control doesn't update it style

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I'm bulding an app in Winform using User Controls.

The problem is that when I update my user control (refering to the style) the forms where it is used don't realized that. If I add some code behind that works, but not the style.

This is the last version of one of my UC.
[image]

This is how it is shown in the form
[image]

The real problem is the space between the label and the textbox! I need to remove it.
I tried cleaning the bulding, updated the control panel, but nothing works.

Comment: Did you recompile the `Form` after your recent change to the `UserControl` in question?

Comment: Yes, I made the user controls some time ago, and I'm working in the proyect so I build the app several times

Comment: to get rid of that space you can try using `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: We cannot help you without source code. Create a POC (proof of concept) project, and post a link to it here.